# Why is training a random forest regressor with MAE criterion so slow compared to MSE?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

When training on even small applications (<50K rows <50 columns) using the mean absolute error criterion for sklearn's RandomForestRegress is nearly 10x slower than using mean squared error. To illustrate even on a small data set:

```
import time
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

def fit_rf_criteria(criterion, X=X, y=y):
    reg = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,
                                criterion=criterion,
                                n_jobs=-1,
                                random_state=1)
    start = time.time()
    reg.fit(X, y)
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)

fit_rf_criteria('mse')  # 0.13266682624816895
fit_rf_criteria('mae')  # 1.26043701171875
```

Why does using the 'mae' criterion take so long for training a RandomForestRegressor? I want to optimize MAE for larger applications, but find the speed of the RandomForestRegressor tuned to this criterion prohibitively slow.

Comment: have you seen this https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9626

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thank you @[hellpanderr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4016674/hellpanderr) for sharing [a reference to the project issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9553#issuecomment-324484928). To summarize – when the random forest regressor optimizes for MSE it optimizes for the L2-norm and a mean-based impurity metric. But when the regressor uses the MAE criterion it optimizes for the L1-norm which amounts to calculating the median. Unfortunately, sklearn's the regressor's implementation for MAE appears to take O(N^2) currently.

Comment: Interesting. The more I learn about sklearn's tree-based models, the more I find how many drawbacks they actually have. For instance, their handling of categorical features is also unoptimal. Is the alternative to use H2O, or would you recommend something else?